# How to access sqlite in Flex

Tags: database, sqlite, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a Sqlite database file from my client, It has different tables in it, and I can also see data in these tables from different sqlite viewers.
This database file is not created in Flex. Its extension is sqlite (`fileName.sqlite`).

But when I try to access these tables through a query from Flex (action script), it throws an error:

> 3115 Table not found

even though the name of table is 100% correct as in database.

Sqlite files created in flex are accessible in flex, but I have to use that sqlite file which was not created in flex.

Can anybody please tell me how can we use sqlite database files in FLEX?

////////////////////////////////////////////////
Below is my code here.

```
private var _sqlconnection:SQLConnection
    private var getPageFromAyatStatement:SQLStatement;
    public function connect():void { 
        _sqlconnection =new SQLConnection();
        _sqlconnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN,onOpenDB);
        _sqlconnection.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR,handlerSqlOpenError);
        var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("abc.sqlite");
        _sqlconnection.openAsync(dbFile); 
    }

    private function onOpenDB(e:SQLEvent):void {
        getPageFromAyat();
    }


    private function getPageFromAyat():void {
        getPageFromAyatStatement = new SQLStatement;
        getPageFromAyatStatement.sqlConnection =_sqlconnection;
        var sql:String = "SELECT * FROM Ayat"
        getPageFromAyatStatement.text=sql;
        getPageFromAyatStatement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT,ayatStatementResult);
        getPageFromAyatStatement.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR,selectDbPathError);
        getPageFromAyatStatement.execute();
    }
    private function ayatStatementResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
        var sqlResult:SQLResult = getPageFromAyatStatement.getResult();
        if(sqlResult.data != null)
        {
            trace(sqlResult.toString())
        }
    }
    private function selectDbPathError(event:SQLErrorEvent):void  { 
    }

    private function handlerSqlOpenError(e:SQLErrorEvent):void {
    }
```

It open database file correctly and even also run getPageFromAyatStatement correctly but show error 'no such table: Ayat'
But I can see all the data in Ayat table from sqlite viewer.

Comment: The ActionScript SQLLite classes are part of the AIR Runtime; not part of the Flex Framework.  Please show your code to create the SQLLite connection; and query.  It may be a problem with you code.  It may be a problem with the versioning of the sqllite database.

Comment: Can you please review my code plz.

Comment: Have you checked the table name? maybe it is case sensitive so ayat is not the same as Ayat.

Also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160865/sql-error-no-such-table?rq=1