# updating sqlite db throws 'no such table' error in fb 4.6

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

Im using FlashBuilder 4.6 and have a simple app that Im working on.  It uses sqlite db and I have mxml components that
1.) lets me ADD a new record
2.) list records in the db with a list component and then when one is clicked,
3.) use input fields to MODIFY the db record selected

Every aspect is working fine, db creation (if doesnt already exist), list component shows all the records, and ADDING new entries works and stores them successfully...

problem is in the UPDATE function.    I KNOW the table exists in the db because I use other components to ADD new records and to list them out... (have verified the database and table names are consistent across all functions) but for some reason when I try to execute the following UPDATE routine it spits out

```
SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'no such table: 'tblquiz'', operation:'execute', detailID:'2013'
```

here is the actionscript3 code Im trying to run to allow the user to UPDATE the db record:

```
private function updateQuestion():void
        {

            var dbFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("database.db");
            var dbConnection:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();
            dbConnection.open(dbFile);

            var statement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            statement.sqlConnection = dbConnection;

            // TAKE THE FORM FIELD VALUES AND USE THIS SQL STATEMENT TO UPDATE THE DATABASE RECORD WHERE THE ID MATCHES DATA.ID
            statement.text = "UPDATE tblquiz SET question = '" + fieldQuestion + "', answerA = '" + fieldAnswerA + "', answerB = '" + fieldAnswerB + "', answerC = '" + fieldAnswerC + "' WHERE id = " + data.id;
            trace(statement.text);

            statement.execute();

            // GO BACK TO THE LIST COMPONENT TO SEE IF THE UPDATE WORKED
            navigator.popView();

        }
```

what am I missing here?  everything else that refers to the database and table works fine I've found nothing in my Googling that sheds any light on this error.   error happens on device connected by USB and on the AIR emulator on the desktop machine Im developing on.

thanks in advance!

UPDATE: problem solved...   i used different paths the database in the app... applicationDirectory in some places and applicationStorageDirectory in others....   so I changed all to:

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("database.db");
```

... which I believe is the method that works across both ios and android (though android is all Im concerned with at the moment).  thanks for your help - cant believe I missed that earlier.  I'll blame lack of sleep.

Comment: Can you run `sqlite3 database.db`, from the command line, and list out what tables are actually in that db file?

Comment: where exaclty am I to run that?  from within FB?  the macbook pro Im working on doesnt have sqlite installed I dont think but it (sqlite) is inside AIR, so it runs within the AIR emulator and in AIR on my android phone.  again, the list component successfully 'gets' the stored values just fine...   and now I no longer get the errors but the updates are NOT saved -- just keeps showing the old values and never saves / stores the updates.   i actually had something to chase after when I was getting the error, but now absolutely nothing but silence - but no success in getting it to save changes.

Comment: @RedCricket  - ok, few hours of sleep and woke up and tackled this again...  I DID use command line to check database.db ...    it shows the path to it as

    /private/tmp/database.db

this thread seems to be similar to what Im dealing with I think - or something similar, i just cant figure out what to change to make sure the copy of the database is the same that my list component is using.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160865/sql-error-no-such-table .  in FB4.6 i can see database.db in the src/bin-debug/ folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved....  turns out i used different paths the database in the app... applicationDirectory in some places and applicationStorageDirectory in others.... so I changed all to:

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("database.db");
```

... which I believe is the method that works across both ios and android (though android is all Im concerned with at the moment). thanks for your help - cant believe I missed that earlier. I'll blame lack of sleep.

Comment: nice to see self-answered questions ;) btw, applicationStorageDirectory works on all platforms - not just ios and android

Comment: Im still patting myself on the back....   and yet dealing with the next issue... but solving new problems is what makes it fun!  (about as geeky as one can get). 
    @LeeBurrows